# Changing height of buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to change the height of a couple of buttons in my app.

[image: my app screenshot]

I have tried setting `@android:color/transparent` as the `android:background` and I have also tried setting a `layout_height` to values like `16dp`.

How could I give my buttons a smaller height?

Here is the style xml:

```
<style name="Theme.PMBAppTheme.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/text_button_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ff3300</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">20sp</item>
</style>
```

And the layout:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/register_btn_privacy"
        android:text="@string/privacy_policy" 
        style="@style/Theme.PMBAppTheme.TextButton"
        />
```

`text_button_text`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/muted_pink_over" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/muted_pink_over" /> 
    <item android:color="@color/muted_pink" /> 
</selector>
```

Comment: Can you post your XML

Comment: @Kirk - sorry, totally forgot to do it. It's there now.

Answer (score 4):

set the height of the button to wrap_content:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

That should set the height of the button to its minimum to display its text.

Comment: I already had it set to `wrap_content` and that produces the above result :(

Answer (score 1):

In [Vapor API](http://vapor-api.com) (a jQuery style framework for Android I just released) there is a method you can use called `.size(int,int)`. This sets the size of your `View` depending on the type of container in which it sits. So something like:

```
$.Button(R.id.register_btn_privacy).size(int width, int height);
```

What's cool is, you can also chain calls to adjust the other properties of your `View`. For example:

```
$.Button(R.id.register_btn_privacy)
.size(50,100)    // set size
.text("Privacy Policy") // set the text
.bgColor(Color.RED)  // set the background color
.color(Color.WHITE);  // set the text color
```

Check it out if you're interested at the [Vapor API website](http://vapor-api.com), it's basically designed to make Android dev a lot easier and like using jQuery.

Comment: This does look interesting but I'm really just starting out with android development. It would be nice to learn how to do things without any additional frameworks/libraries.

Comment: That's fair enough! Just throwing it out there because when I first came to Android I found it all a bit confusing. Best of luck with it all

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from your style

```
<item name="android:height">20sp</item>
```

So you end up with

```
<style name="Theme.PMBAppTheme.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/text_button_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ff3300</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>
```

`Button` inherits from `TextView` and according to `TextView` [android:height](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aheight), this is probably setting the height exactly and causing it to ignore your `layout_height`.

Comment: Thanks but this was a no go as well. I think I'm going to have to use a `TextView` and make it clickable instead of a `Button`.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `@drawable/text_button_text` too? Maybe something unexpected in there.

Comment: What happens if you clean your project? After that height property of your style? Also what happens if you remove the style from your button all together and clean the project?